# How to take numbers from a string and compare with other values?

Tags: python, list, numbers

Having a string like this one:

```
server volume1 0%              
server volume2 10%              
server2 volume1 15%
```

Is it possible to select only those that have more than (for example), 10%?

To take the percentages, I use this regex:

```
match = re.findall("\d+%", string)
```

The output is like this:

```
['0%', '10%', '15%']
```

But How could I operate with that?

The desired output could be something like this:

```
warning: server.volume2 = 10%, server2.volume1 = 15%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When programming, percentages are turned into decimals instead by dividing the number by `100`, that way they behave nicely when used for arithmetics. For example if you want `10%` of `1000`, you can get that by `0.1*1000=100` - i.e. you translate `10%` to `0.1`

So what you could do, would be something like

```py
match = re.findall("\d+%", string)
match2 = [int(x.replace('%', ''))/100 for x in match]
```

Then you could assign the server volumes to these numbers and easily check if `volume > 0.1` (or whichever boundary you wish to set)

Answer (score 1):

So, you've made half the work. You made them into a list, BUT, I fear you need to change that...
Because you don't store which volume does that precent contain,
A solution is:

```py
string = """server volume1 10%
server volume2 5%
server2 volume1 15%""" # replace with real string
finalString = "warning: "
matchArr = string.split("\n")
for i in matchArr:
  tmpMatchArr = i.split(" ")
  for i in range(0, len(tmpMatchArr)):
    if int(tmpMatchArr[2].replace("%", "")) < 10:
      break
    if i == 2:
      finalString += " = " + tmpMatchArr[i] + ", "
    elif i == 1:
      finalString += tmpMatchArr[i]
    else:
      finalString += tmpMatchArr[i] + "."
  
print(finalString);
```

This automatically selects precents more than 10, to change it, change the number 10.
I tested it, it works; If it doesn't or doesn't fulfill your requirements, post a comment and I will help!